# com.atomikos.icatch.SysException Error : Couldn't get lock for /var/lib/tomcat6/./tm.out

Tags: spring, ubuntu, tomcat6, atomikos

I have problem deploying a Spring project in Ubuntu with Tomcat6, whereas it didn't occur when deploying in window.

The error logs show this ;

> PropertyAccessException 1:
>   org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property
>   'transactionTimeout' threw exception; nested exception is
>   com.atomikos.icatch.SysException: Error in init(): Couldn't get lock
>   for /var/lib/tomcat6/./tm.out at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1361)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
>   at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4206)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4705)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1276)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:625)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doGet(HTMLManagerServlet.java:136)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:186)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:563)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested
>   PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are: PropertyAccessException 1:
>   org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property
>   'transactionTimeout' threw exception; nested exception is : Couldn't
>   get lock for /var/lib/tomcat6/./tm.out at
>   org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:102)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58)
>   at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358)
>   ... 36 more Dec 01, 2012 3:30:06 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: Closing Spring
>   root WebApplicationContext Dec 01, 2012 3:30:07 AM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: HTMLManager:
>   list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'

Please help me find how to fix this error..

Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you sure that the folder is writeable for the user tomcat is running on, maybe you can move it to another place http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256415/how-to-move-location-of-atomikoss-tm-out-and-epoch-files

Comment: Are you sure you do not have another process running which is using atomikos ?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm facing this problem and need a workaround asap..